# Cannot start Java (Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll )

Tags: windows-7, java, dll

I installed Java on my computer (windows-7) but when I try to start any java application (the java web validator test or a normal jar file) it does not start.

I always get:

> "Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll".

I have tried Java 8 v152, 151, 144, 131

[image: Error message]

Can anybody think of an idea why this isn't working thank you very much

Comment: You've to install C++ redistributions.

Comment: I have already installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package" from https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=8328. Also java is trying to use the DLL that came with the Java installer (also in java/bin) and not the system one. When I rename/remove the local one it is trying to use the system DLL but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Advokat - Did you install the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the package?  If after you delete the file in the application directory, and you get the same error, it actually means it is NOT attempting to use the file in the application directory.  Edit your question.  Please do not respond with a comment.

Comment: Place that **msvcr100.dll** in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre` folder as said in that error. May be you've 32 bit Java, so install 32bit C++ redist.([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5555)).

Comment: Encountered the same problem today with Java 1.8.0_151 on a Windows 7 system. Could not find a solution yet. Both 32-bit and 64-bit Java exhibit the same behaviour.